# PHP SDK - redirect issue after asking user's permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have an application which is in a Facebook fan page's tab.

When a user access to this page's tab, I request to him some permissions.

My issue is that, when the user accept the permissions, he is redirected to http://apps.facebook.com/ and not the page's tab.

`$my_url = "https://apps.facebook.com/<my_app_name>/";`

If I change my_url value to http://www.facebook.com/pages/, then the user is on an infinite loop.

My code:

```
 if (isset($_REQUEST["code"])) {
  $code = $_REQUEST["code"];
 }
 if(empty($code)) {
  // Get permission from the user to manage their Page.
  $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
    . "&scope=read_stream";
  echo('<script>top.location.href="' . $dialog_url . '";</script>');
 } else {
 //my code
 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `code` variable is never passed to the contents of your iFrame tab via the Fan Page/Application Tab URL (if you use an application tab URL no additional parameters will be passed to the iFrame URL). As such, going by the code example above the, JavaScript redirect to the authentication dialog will always passed to the client browser.

You should look at using the latest PHP SDK (v3.1.1) with the JavaScript SDK to do your authentication:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/534/

Code example from the above blog post:

```
require 'php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));

// See if there is a user from a cookie
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
    $user = null;
  }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <body>
    <?php if ($user_profile) { ?>
      Your user profile is 
      <pre>            
        <?php print htmlspecialchars(print_r($user_profile, true)) ?>
      </pre> 
    <?php } else { ?>
      <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
    <?php } ?>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>               
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>', 
          cookie: true, 
          xfbml: true,
          oauth: true
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've been looking for this question the whole day, but doesn't work. When user didn't authorize app, a fb login button shows, which opens a popup with an error and not the oauth permissions dialog... look: http://i.imgur.com/bVFvd.jpg